# Rewriting jQuery to plain old JavaScript - are the performance gains worth it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, jquery

Since jQuery is an incredibly easy and banal library, I've developed a rather complex project fairly quickly with it. The entire interface is jQuery based, and memory is cleaned regularly to maintain optimum performance. Everything works very well in Firefox, and exceptionally so in Chrome (other browsers are of no concern for me as this is not a commercial or publicly available product).

What I'm wondering now is - since pure plain old banal JavaScript is really not a complicated language to master, would it be performance enhancing to rewrite the whole thing in plain old JavaScript, and if so, how much of a boost would you expect to get from it?

If the answers prove positive enough, I'll go ahead and do it, run a benchmark and report back with the precise findings.

Edit: Thanks guys, valuable insight. The purpose was not to "re-invent the wheel" - it was just for experience and personal improvement. Just because something exists, doesn't mean you shouldn't explore it into greater detail, know how it works or try to recreate it. This is the same reason I seldom use frameworks, I would much rather use my own code and iron it out and gain massive experience doing it, than start off by using someone else's code, regardless of how ironed out it is. Anyway, I won't be doing it, thanks for saving me the effort :)

Comment: So , you are plannin to Re-invent the Wheel !!!!

Comment: @Konerak: Calm down. @Clyde: No, I just want to see if it drives as well as the not so recently invented one.

Comment: If you really have to, you should try to optimize your jQuery code first. E.g. selectors. And of course normal stuff like reducing the number of iterations in a loop etc (this applies to any code whether you use jQuery or not).

Comment: @Swader: I meant no offense. I was just hoping my exaggeration could **get you thinking** on the reasons why not to do it in assembler - because the reasons why not to do it in plain JavaScript are pretty similar.

Comment: @Felix: Of course, I've been working on that from the ground up, so there's not much left to optimize there, unless someone can offer some incredible links with jQuery optimization secrets exposed. I believe I did a fairly good job with the whole thing, memory consumption stays under 5MB the whole time and the site is enormous. Still, there's always room for improvement, so any advice is welcomed.

Comment: @Swader: Ok then. I'd say it is not worth the effort. But it also depends on what you are using jQuery for. Replicating the selector engine in plain JavaScript is a pain if you have to consider browsers that don't support `querySelectorAll`. Of course it is easier for some selectors than for others. But the advantage of jQuery is that you can concentrate on **what** you want to do instead of **how**. You can always do it as an exercise for you of course...

Comment: @Konerak, @Clyde, @Swader: I'm puzzled by people continually comparing the difference between assembler and JavaScript to the difference between DOM and jQuery. Can't you see it's absurd? jQuery is a tiny abstraction compared to that, and **DOM really isn't that hard**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say the site works from "very well" to "exceptionally" - then *don't bother*. It won't be worth the effort, and there is no guarantee that your end result will even be more optimal than with jQuery, as the jQuery team has had years to iron out many issues.

You also say that plain old JS is "really not a complicated language" - that's not the main issue. It's not JS that's difficult to master, and what jQuery makes up for, but all the various browser quirks.

In the end, even if you do create a site that is marginally faster without jQuery, you have one that is much harder to maintain.

In short, there *are* times when doing such an exercise is valuable, but *not* when your site already works "very well", and it's not necessarily as simple as you think.

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother.

Sure you can gain some performance by using vanilla js, and in some edgecases it is worth it, but overall, as along as you use jQuery well, your gains from vanilla js are insignificant, and the crossbrowser support loss is not.

Why reinvent the wheel?

If you do wish to polish of your implementation look for places where you can store and reuse references to DOM elements, so you don't have to traverse the DOM every time you need to use them.

Comment: Cross browser support isn't that important, since I'm only on FF (during development) and using the system exclusively in Chrome. I'm currently in the process of hunting down the last few bits where I excessively traverse, yes. Any other advice on optimization? What else can I do to make things faster/lighter?

Comment: The things i usually avoid are: unnecessarily  complex selectors - preferably all selectors start with an id or has a very limited scope, loop constructs that create a new callstack for each iteration (.each .filter and such), unnecessary DOM manipulations - for instance appends inside loops (build strings, append when done). There are many more ways to optimize your jquery usage, but the answer doesn't belong in this note - search through SO and use google and i am sure you'll find much inmspiration

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. The things you mentioned are already at a bare minimum I believe, but I do intend to run through the JS code at least a couple more times to give it some longevity.

Answer (score 4):

### No.

I'm sorry, but unless you are as skilled as the jQuery developers, **this might not be a good idea**.

Yes, you **might cut out some code** that does not get used, and you **might maybe even gain a bit of performance**. But if you are not as skilled, you'll probably end up **missing a lot of improvements** the team implemented and won't even gain speed.

The biggest reason why people prefer jQuery over JavaScript is the **speed of development**, the **maintainability** and the **cross-browser interoperability**. You risk missing out on all that.

- **Higher-level code** means faster development, but also faster support in the future. Finding and fixing a bug in high-level code is easier.
- The jQuery code will be **updated by the team** when new issues are found or new browsers arrive. You will have to duplicate all these changes in your own code.
- Should you encounter a bug in your own code, **you're on your own**. If you encounter difficulties with jQuery scripts, there is an enormous userbase that can help you.
- And don't get me started on all the **plugins** that exist. What if tomorrow your client wants you to add widget X to your site, and you don't have jQuery? Will you re-invent that plugin too?

Comment: I'm most certainly not as skilled as them, no, but I do hope to be one day, and what better way to get there than to experiment and reverse-engineer. Good point on the plugins though.

Answer (score 3):

[The root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Normally url only answers are not suitable for upvoting but actually this document may serve me well in some peer to peer discussions.